# EntityFrameworkCore with sqlite on Xamarin.Mac

Tags: c#, visual-studio-mac, xamarin.mac, ef-core-3.1, sqlite-net

Having issues to get EntityFrameworkCore working in Visual Studio for Mac targeting Xamarin.Mac with framework version 4.7.2.

A sample demonstrating the issue can be found here (all info can also be found in the readme.md):

https://github.com/nvanlaerebeke/EFCore_XamarinMac

The steps to create the sample above were the following:

- Create a new Cocoa app
- Switch to Xamarin.Mac Full, framework version 4.7.2 in my case
- Add entity framework core nuget packages
- Add entity framework core sqlite nuget packages
- Create the context and model/entity
- Try to run a query

When using Xamarin.Modern the above steps work, when using the Xamarin.Mac it gives a e_sqlite3 not found.

The exception is:

```
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnection' threw an exception. ---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Exception: Library e_sqlite3 not found
```

For the full stacktrace see the sample on github

As the exception mentions, it cannot find the libe_sqlite3.dylib, no matter where I put it, it can't seem to find it automatically.
The only way to get the app to find the dylib is when setting "DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH"

For example (with mono logging on):

```
MONO_LOG_LEVEL=debug MONO_LOG_MASK=dll DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=<PATH_TO_DYLIB_DIR> ./Contents/MacOS/XamarinMac_EFCore
```

I think the dylib is loaded here:

https://github.com/ericsink/SQLitePCL.raw/blob/dba1792289cd17fcd96c10f62597c212187e42be/src/SQLitePCLRaw.nativelibrary/for_netstandard2.cs#L376

Does anyone know how to get this working?, been playing around with the nuget packages and dllmap but have had no luck so far

Comment: Are you using the linker?

Comment: Didn't continue to look into it, switched everything to Xamarin.Modern from Xamarin.Full, the ticket is still open but some people did post a work around: https://github.com/ericsink/SQLitePCL.raw/issues/358